# Error:(2367, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorButtonNormal' with value '@color/blue_grey_500')

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I´m using Android studio and when I Generate a signed APK its show me an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> Error:(2367, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'colorButtonNormal' with value '@color/blue_grey_500').
>
> Error:(2367, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'colorButtonNormal' with value '@color/blue_grey_500').

And this error is in here (in file res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue_grey_500</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if u have `blue_grey_500` in `colors.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the color manually in your colors.xml

```
<color name="blue_grey_500">#9E9E9E</color>
```